# react interpolation of background url not rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'm teaching myself React, it's been hard, excuse my bad verbiage here as it's all still very new to me.

I'm trying to write a component that will render a background image on a certain page depending on the props given.  I have come up that with interpolation this may work however I'm not achieving the effect I want.

So let's say in my component called `blog.js` I have

```
<BgImage image="blog" />
```

Then my component that should render the background I have:

```
import React from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import blog from '../../static/blog.jpg';
import about from '../../static/about.jpg';
import contact from '../../static/contact.jpg';
import projects from '../../static/projects.jpg';

const BgBackground = styled.div`
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  position: absolute;
  &::after {
    background-size: cover;
    content: "";
    opacity: 0.25;
    height: 400px;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
  }
`

class BgImage extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
  <BgBackground style={{background: 'url' + this.props.image}} />
    );
  }
}

export default BgImage;
```

I don't get an error but I get these warnings because nothing is being used:

```
3:8  warning  'blog' is defined but never used      no-unused-vars
4:8  warning  'about' is defined but never used     no-unused-vars
5:8  warning  'contact' is defined but never used   no-unused-vars
6:8  warning  'projects' is defined but never used  no-unused-vars
```

I'm at a loss and don't know what to do from here.  Any thoughts? (I'm very well aware something is wrong or broken, I just can't figure it out)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. Remember that in React, props are changed to camelCase, so properties with dashes have no effect:

```
<BgBackground style={{backgroundImage: 'url( "${this.props.image}" )' }} />
```

Comment: ok that makes 100% sense to me and thank you.  I want it to work so bad but I get this error: `warning  Unexpected template string expression  no-template-curly-in-string`

Comment: Remove the single quotes and replace those with back ticks  for the template literal to work. Sorry about that (it is the button that is to the left of the number 1 on your keyboard, or right on top of the tab button)

Comment: still doesn't render, but it FEELS like it should! arrg :D

Comment: if I put `<BgBackground style={{background: 'url( "${about}" )' }} />` it renders just fine.  So I think now the props isn't passing.  

In my about.js component I have 

`<BgImage image="about" />`

Comment: Use backticks -> **`\``**, not a quote symbol -> **`'`** in string interpolation syntax: `<BgBackground style={{backgroundImage: \`url( "${this.props.image}" )\` }} />`. Just like the one you use after `styled.div` to write inline css syntax.

Answer (score 0):

```
<BgBackground style={{background-image: 'url( "${this.props.image}" )' }} />
```

Comment: can't do dashes in jsx and it throws this warning: 

`warning  Unexpected template string expression  no-template-curly-in-string`